# Passing the all column values to a multibinding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, multibinding

I have a ListView that is configured as a GridView. It is databound to a DataTable and displays several columns of ints. I'd like to display the maximum value in each column in the bold font.

To do this, I have a MultiBinding on the FontWeight of each cell. It is easy enough to pass the cell value to the MultiBinding converter. But how do I pass all of the items in that column to the converter? Or is there a way to pass the the entire databound DataTable to the converter?

Comment: Any luck getting this implemented? If you need any more clarification, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is expose your DataTable in the view itself as a property. Then with your converter bind to the DataTable and set ConverterParameter to the name of the column.

```
... FontWeight="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MaxValueConverter}, ElementName=MyControl, Path=MyDataTable, ConverterParameter='ColumnName'}"/>
```

Unfortunately, you can't do this..

```
... FontWeight="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MaxValueConverter}, Path={Binding}}"/>
```

..but it would make binding to the DataContext much easier.